# Azure QnA Maker - add multiple URLs through REST API

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I have a working QnA Maker instance, I manually added a few URLs to public websites.

Now I want to add many more URLs.  I guess this means mastering the REST API? What method should I call? Any examples to start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this sample, which got me started:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/quickstarts/create-new-kb-python

It's an example of calling the REST API's "Knowledgebase - Create" operation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase/create

It crashes if you add more than 10 URLs. Eventually, I found there are limits of 10 URLs on create.

Adding more requires a separate REST call - "Knowledgebase - Update" with an "add" node in the request body.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase/update

I think this is limited to 5 URLs per call.  I extended the python code to loop over my list of URLs and "add" them all.  It seems to work but gets slower and slower to complete each call.  My guess is QnA Maker re-runs some internal indexing logic over the whole knowledge base on every update call?  If so then that limit per call is probably counter-productive.